# Unable to use the `==` argument of `capsh` to re-exec it?

Tags: linux, debian, shell, capabilities

I am experimenting with `capsh` of `libcap2-bin` (1:2.32-1), but have found that I'm unable to use the `==` argument to re-exec `capsh`.

In particular, when I'm using the `capsh`'s `==` argument, it's complaining that it couldn't `execve(2)` the `/bin/bash` shell?

Does anyone experiment a similar problem?

```
ls -la /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1183448 Jun 18  2020 /bin/bash

capsh --help
...
==             re-exec(capsh) with args as for --
...

capsh == --print
execve /bin/bash failed!

capsh --print
Current: =
Bounding set =cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read
Ambient set =
Securebits: 00/0x0/1'b0
 secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)
 secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-ambient-raise: no (unlocked)
uid=1000(parallels) euid=1000(parallels)
gid=1000(parallels)
groups=4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare),1000(parallels)
Guessed mode: UNCERTAIN (0)
```

Comment: This was fixed in libcap-2.45 (see my answer for the reported bug and fixes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that it's trying to re-execute itself as `capsh` (or whatever command name and path you started it with).

This is from `strace capsh == --print`:

```
execve("capsh", ["capsh", "--print"], [/* 20 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "execve /bin/bash failed!\n", 25execve /bin/bash failed!
) = 25
```

So it's not really "`execve /bin/bash`" that fails but `execve capsh`.  The `execve()` function does not do lookups in `$PATH`.

Using `capsh` with its full path would make it work.

```
$ command -v capsh
/sbin/capsh
$ /sbin/capsh == --print
Current: =
[... etc. ...]
```

See also the `execve(2)` manual on your system (`man 2 execve`).

Comment: Thank you. So, it's a bug that it says `execve /bin/bash failed!`? I've never seen `command -v <prog>` be used to obtain the absolute pathname for a program - is it intended for that?

Comment: @Shuzheng The message is clearly misleading as `execve()` was not invoked for `/bin/bash` but for `capsh`. `command -v` is intended to be used for outputting the path to the utility given as an argument. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html

Comment: — I don’t see why to use `command -v` instead of `which`? By “utility”, you mean any program in `$PATH`?

Comment: @Shuzheng You can use whatever command you fancy for figuring out the absolute path to `capsh`. I used `command -v`, because it's standard and it works the same in all standard shells on all Unix systems. I don't quite know why this is an issue.

Comment: Now I have enough reputation to comment, I'd like to point out that this bug was fixed upstream in 2020 - v2.45 and later have that fix (more details in my answer below).

Answer (score 3):

This is likely a bug in libcap:capsh we fixed last year:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209873

If this is still a problem in libcap releases after 2.45 let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If the [source code I found](https://github.com/mhiramat/libcap/blob/master/progs/capsh.c) is correct, it looks to use the same few lines for both `==` and `--`:

```
    } else if ((!strcmp("--", argv[i])) || (!strcmp("==", argv[i]))) {
        argv[i] = strdup(argv[i][0] == '-' ? "/bin/bash" : argv[0]);
        argv[argc] = NULL;
        execve(argv[i], argv+i, envp);
        fprintf(stderr, "execve /bin/bash failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Like Kusalananda said, it won't find `capsh` since `execve()` doesn't look in the path, and the error message is hardcoded for the `/bin/bash` case.

Comment: That github repository is a pretty stale clone. The upstream sources are here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git .

Comment: @AndrewGMorgan, yes, looks like the [same code is there](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/tree/progs/capsh.c?h=libcap-2.32&id=13227f9b2f2b2f222e8022e19bd46db6f6f898c6#n770) (until [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/commit/progs/capsh.c?id=cbca9abc73acf779a3110baa0d3c66960951b1fa) from 2020-04).